# How to map a JPA bidirectional relationship involving an abstract class?

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

Assuming the following simple schema:

**Entity table** - attributes common to all entities

```
entityId, timeCreated,...
```

**Comments table** - some entities have a collection of these

```
entityId, commentId, commentText,....
```

**Person table.**

```
pensonId (entityId), firstName, lastName,...
```

And the following Java inheritance structure:

```
BaseEntity - abstract - entity, join inheritance with a discriminator
    CommentedEntity - abstract - introduces `comments` collection - mapping tbd
        Person - concrete - entity - mapping trivial
```

How would we map bidirectional relationship between `CommentedEntity` and `Comment`? The code below is my best interpretation of examples I have found.

**CommentedEntity**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Comment**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="entityId", referencedColumnName="entityId")
private CommentedEntity owner;
```

- Since `CommentedEntity` is an abstract class, this doesn't work.
  `owner` references an unknown entity.
- Making `CommentedEntity` an entity, would require giving it an id, so I don't think that makes
  sense.
- Since multiple concrete entities will have `comments`
  collection, concrete entity name cannot be used in mapping.

How would we then bidirectionally map a person.commentList property?

Comment: You have a OneToMany in __Person__ across to type __Comment__, but no idea what that type is. You have a ManyToOne in __CommentedEntity__ to __CommentedEntity__?! (do you mean __Person__?) As long as the field types are consistent and are persistable (Entity or MappedSuperclass) then you should be able to do this (or at least I can with the implementation that I use) like this http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#join_bi

Comment: Sorry, Neil. I needed to make a much simpler example and I made a mistake. The question is about bidirectional mapping between `CommentedEntity` and a `Comment`. `Person` is not in play, as it would inherit this mapping from its parent. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've looked at the link you provided. My case is just as the Account/Address one with the FK. Where you use concrete `Account`, I'd need to put an abstract `CommentedEntity`.

Comment: Ok, and that is what works for me with the implementation I use. So what happens when you do that? (exact exception+stack trace?, or result)

Comment: `CommentedEntity` is an unknown entity. That's the exception and it makes sense, as it's not mapped as an entity. It's only an intermediate abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

If `Person` extends `CommentedEntity` then you wouldn't need an `CommentedEntity` `owner` for the `Person` entity because `Person is part of a`CommentedEntity`. In other words, there is no need for an owner field because a Person is a CommentedEntity.

Comment: But a bidirectional mapping requires an owner. `mappedBy="owner"`. Can you provide an example of how you'd map this?

Comment: There is no bidirectional mapping the way you are describing it. It is merely one entity, `Person` which is a subclass of `CommentedEntity`, which is a subclass of `BaseEntity`. What is it that has a collection of `Persons`?